# Implementing a stack using an array

Tags: c++, stack

I just implemented a stack using an array and am curious as to why people start their tops at -1. Is it more inefficient to start at 0? I have a programming assignment to implement a stack that performs basic functions, and tried doing it on my own first.

After I got it to work I looked around to see other implementations. Most people start their tops at -1. Is there a benefit to that? Is it wrong to start at 0?

here's my working code:

```
header file: 
#ifndef H_Stack
#define H_Stack

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct nodeType
{
    int info;
    nodeType *link;
};

class arrayStack
{
private:
    int stackSize;
    int stackTop;
    int *stackArray;

public:
    arrayStack(const int &x);
    void push(const int &x);
    bool is_full();
    bool is_empty();
    int size();
    int top();
    void pop();
    ~arrayStack();
};

class linkedStack
{
private:
    nodeType *stackTop;

public:
    linkedStack();
    void push(const int &x);
    int size();
    int top();
    void pop();
    bool is_empty();
    ~linkedStack();
};

#endif
```

Imp file:

```
#include "stack.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

arrayStack::arrayStack(const int &x)
{
    if (x <= 0)
    {
        stackSize = 20;
        stackArray = new int[stackSize];
    }

    else
    {
        stackTop = 0;
        stackSize = x;
        stackArray = new int[stackSize];
    }
}

bool arrayStack::is_full()
{
    return (stackTop == stackSize);
}

void arrayStack::push(const int &x)
{
    if (!is_full())
    {
        stackArray[stackTop] = x;
        stackTop++;
    }
}

bool arrayStack::is_empty()
{
    return (stackTop == 0);
}

int arrayStack::size()
{
    return stackSize;
}

int arrayStack::top()
{
    assert(stackTop != 0);

    return stackArray[stackTop - 1];
}

void arrayStack::pop()
{
    if (!is_empty())
        stackTop--; 

    else
    {
        cout << "can't pop from an empty stack.";
    }
}

arrayStack::~arrayStack()
{
    delete[] stackArray; 
}

linkedStack::linkedStack()
{
    stackTop = nullptr;
}

void linkedStack::push(const int &x)
{
    nodeType *newNode;
    newNode = new nodeType;
    newNode->info = x;
    newNode->link = stackTop;
    stackTop = newNode;
}

int linkedStack::size()
{

    int count = 0;
    nodeType *temp;
    temp = stackTop;

    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        temp = temp->link;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}

int linkedStack::top()
{
    assert(stackTop != nullptr);

    return stackTop->info;
}

void linkedStack::pop()
{
    assert(!is_empty());

        nodeType *temp = stackTop;
        stackTop = stackTop->link;
        delete temp;

}

bool linkedStack::is_empty()
{
    return (stackTop == nullptr);
}

linkedStack::~linkedStack()
{
    while (stackTop != nullptr)
    {
        pop();
    }
}
```

it successfully pops/pushes. It is not circular so its not efficient or very useful... but I had to write it for school.

Comment: Please, remove that `using namespace std;` from your header file.

Comment: What's wrong with [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) that makes you feel you need to roll your own?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I have to implement one for school. There's nothing wrong with the built in one

Comment: Having `top` be -1 can be an easy way of showing the stack is currently empty. leaving `top` at index 0 can imply to some people that index 0 is being used. But again, this is all just programming methods. If you feel more comfortable leaving top at 0 and your stack works properly, more power to you.

Comment: @izzyk2517 All right. No problem :) was just currious and missed the "for school" bit when I read your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an initial top of `-1` allows you to implement `push` with just:

```
    stackArray[++stackTop] = x;
```

That said, an initial top of `0` would just need an equally efficient, if slightly more verbose two-liner:

```
    stackArray[stackTop] = x;
    ++stackTop;
```

or to keep it a one-liner:

```
    stackArray[stackTop++] = x;
```

where the latter is perfectly fine *as long as the top is a primitive type* (for user-defined classes, post-increment is significantly less efficient, as it necessarily involves a complete copy of the state; some people avoid post-increment in C++ in general to develop habits that don't cause problems for user-defined classes).

Point is, there is no special benefit to `-1` vs. `0`; there may be conventions shared by the code you're looking at, but all of it works.

Comment: Thats interesting, so doing ++x is more efficient than x++. I didn't know that. I thought they both made a copy of the variable and added one to the value. How does ++c work if it doesn't do that?

Comment: It's called `preincrement` and `post increment`, there are lots of articles that go into detail on the differences, strategies, etc, that may be out of place for this comment thread! Check it out! :)

Comment: @izzyk2517: To be clear, they're both equally efficient in your code, since `stackTop` is a plain `int`. It's only class types (including stuff like iterators), with explicit overloads for `operator++()` and `operator++(int)`, where the efficiency issues come in. Pre-increment can modify the instance in place, and return a reference to that instance; post-increment must make a copy of the instance, then increment itself in place, then return the copy. With `int`, it's fine either way, but using pre-increment by default is a good habit to have.